# SVG Marker onHover Event (Graph)

Tags: svg

I am building my own line graph and wanted to know how would I go about making a `<path>` line interactive on hover.

For example (simplified):

```
<path d="M5,10L10,20L30,40"></path>
```

How would I execute a hover event when the user hovers over `5,10` or `10,20` and show a `<circle>` or just a command in general? Is there something I'm missing or do I have to detect the mouse's position?

Comment: edited the code, I didn't copy my actual code, so I didn't notice the error. I will search markers right now.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#Markers since I cannot edit the older comment.

Comment: yes, that would be the dots, but I think I'm really looking for how could I attach an event to these markers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796332/chrome-svg-marker-element-onmouseover. I don't understand how this would not be possible, I would expect graphs to have that functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SVG has a concept called markers that allow arbitrary shapes to be added to path nodes but markers cannot receive events, [per the last line in the SVG marker specification text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElement).

*Event attributes and event listeners attached to the contents of a ‘marker’ element are not processed; only the rendering aspects of ‘marker’ elements are processed.*

If you think this should change, [take it up with the w3c SVG group](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/).

If you want to respond to events you'd have to manually create your own shapes and ensure that they happen to be situated at the correct points.

Comment: This will likely become supported in SVG2, see https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#Markers and especially issue 11 "Make interaction work on positioned markers".

Comment: So if the path is hovered, get x,y of the mouse and select the point nearest to those coordinates?

Comment: Sure, [getPointAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) may help with that.

Comment: after researching on what that was, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to use it for XD could you elaborate. I found a script that returns the coordinates of the svg on path hover. http://jsfiddle.net/EfJx8/