# How do add events into the path markers (for example mouseover)?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How do add events into the path markers (for example mouseover)?

I have this code:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");    
defs.selectAll("defs")
.data(module_color_status)
.enter()
.append("marker")
.attr("id", "arrow_end")
.attr("refX", (node_radius / 2) + (interface_radius / 2))
.attr("refY", interface_radius)
.attr("markerWidth", (node_radius / 2) + interface_radius)
.attr("markerHeight", (node_radius / 2) + interface_radius)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", interface_radius)
    .attr("cy", interface_radius)
    .attr("r", interface_radius)
    .attr("style", "stroke: none; fill: #ff000;");
```

And I have been trying to add mouse over event into the marker....but It was fail...

Thanks.

Comment: See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019689/svg-marker-onhover-event-graph#19021488).

Comment: Thanks, well I need to think how I do change the code for make this without markers.