# SVG marker hover

Tags: svg

I would like to display tooltips on markers setup on a `<path>` element.

As several old posts pointed out, any events are not processed on markers as defined by the official SVG standard.

Links:

[SVG Marker onHover Event (Graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019689/svg-marker-onhover-event-graph)

[Chrome SVG marker element onmouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796332/chrome-svg-marker-element-onmouseover)

Questions:

- Since the linked questions are a few years old, is there an update to this? Is this still the case in the current 2021 world to not be able to receive events on marker elements?
- Is there an alternative that is easy to implement and results in fast code for large sets of markers? My only idea currently is to render invisible `<circle>` elements on top of every marker in order to properly process events. Are there better options?

Comment: There is no update to this. It is still the case. Seems like you've thought of the same workaround that everyone else uses.